# Blurr background image, but keep image focussed in box area

Tags: javascript, css, image

Does anyone know a css/javascript technique which does the following:
Fullscreen background-image blurred, but a floating fixed with portion of that image not-blurred, yet that section stays centred and the same size on browser window resize.
The background image needs to resize with the browser window, but the focussed section needs to remain centred and have the same box-size, while its clipped background image resizes together with the blurred background. see example image.
Must be cross-browser compatible.
[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/PpMNWG). My answer is similar to Gaby aka G. Petrioli, so I didn't post again. I use this method from [CSS Secrets book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031123.do), secret 18(Frosted glass effect), [page 146](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nokNCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: That's very close!  I would still need to keep the size of the small box fixed and centred on the page. Yours resizes with the page. See  Gaby aka G. Petrioli's solution for a completely functioning solution. Thanks!

Comment: So you can use `px` instead `vw` and `vh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using two elements (*using the same background image on both*) but setting the `background-attachment` to `fixed` on both.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.blur-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blurred,
.unblurred {
  background: url('//placekitten.com/1000/750') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.blurred {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(7px);
}

.unblurred {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-group">
  <div class="blurred"></div>
  <div class="unblurred"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a version with two images based on yours. I have tested it on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Edge. https://jsfiddle.net/jmfuo/3s232cpz/7/

Answer (score 1):

Make the image responsive with blurr background

**Markup**

```
<div class="widget center">
  <div class="text center">
    <h1 class="">Responsive Blur</h1>
    <p>Resize me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blur">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/88212/pexels-photo-88212.jpeg" class="bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
    -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
    -o-filter: blur(18px);
    filter: blur(18px);
}

.blur {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -20px auto;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blur:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.widget {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
   background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/88212/pexels-photo-88212.jpeg");
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/*  NOT REQUIRED  */

.text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 340px;
}

.text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.text p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

**See the results [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWNPxr)**

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the child image is scaled down  to its container in your example. I need it always by in sync with the blurred background.  It must look like the square is "focusing" the framed area of the blurred background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use image twice, center them, one above the other on a container using absolute position. Then, blur the first one and use clip-path to show a part of a second one. But maybe clip-path support is not enough today for your need :) https://jsfiddle.net/nesquimo/nnmquv1k/2/

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.child:first-child{
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.child:last-child{
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(20% 18% 15% 20%);
  clip-path: inset(20% 18% 15% 20%);
}
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png">
  <img class="child" src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thats about as far as I had gotten. Yet clip-path unfortunately does not work on internet explorer, I believe. Also the clip path only works with inset. I would have to readjust the inset with javascript to keep the size and position of the box when resizing the window. Your example image is nicer than mine, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent container

Add a background to the parent container

Place a div inside the parent container, this div will act a a mask. Add a filter blur property to the mask

Add another div inside the parent. This div will contain your content. Add a background image to this div and center this div using css `transform`

Snippet below

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRney6jjMJ8ZrRKwPb9MNDi7dvF1OLFC78ZpT8Th43WaNnJQV263Q);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid white;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="mask"></div>
  <div id="content"> This is some content</div>
  <div>
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but the bg image must resize with the browser window, and the focussed area must remain centred, the same size, yet its focused image must resize together with the blurred background image. It must look like the square is "focusing" the framed area of the blurred background.

Comment: answer updated check pen here http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/BWXKoL and resize window

Comment: No, that's unfortunately still not it. In your code, the  image in the small box is  a different scale than in the big box. The small box should show the excerpt of the big box, but not blurred. Just like in my example image above. your example scales the unblurred image to the size of the small box.

Comment: @jum you are incorrect...My example scales the background url relative to Viewport width and height of the browser...Also you can simply replace the url of the small image with the url of the big image so they are the same...Is it difficult for you to replace that?

Comment: I did exactly that (used identical image urls) at your example  codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/BWXKoL, befor I wrote my comment,  and the scaling was still not correct. Thanks anyway. See Gaby aka G. Petrioli above, that one is working.